# MobaXTerm "Follow Terminal Folder" STFP and Byobu

Tags: ssh

I am using MobaXTerm to SSH into my remote Ubuntu server. The server already has Byobu installed and running. I noticed that for the STFP feature, the "follow terminal window" feature doesn't work. It defaults to my home directory and I have to move it manually. When I uninstalled Byobu it still didn't work. Does this feature work with Byobu installed? Or otherwise how do you get this work?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the "follow terminal window" feature - regardless to Byobu. In my case I had command in my /etc/bashrc file who print output to the screen (specifically in my case: ntpdate). After I added ' > /dev/null 2>&1' after that command the sftp and the "follow terminal window" feature works fine.
May be that Byobu is adding prints with every connection - in that case it may cause failure in the stfp.

Comment: That did it for me. I had an echo command in .bashrc and after removing it the follow feature started working again.